# How to segue from a Table Cell View in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

This is the code i have to far on the main table view view controller I just don't know how to go about transitioning to a new view controller to a selected cell to display more content about whatever cell was selected.

```
import UIKit

class MainVC: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var Table1: UITableView!
var postArray: [[String]] = []

var postSubject = ""
var postDescription = ""
var postDate = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchData()
}

func fetchData() {
    println("success1")
    postArray = []

    let httpMethod = "GET"

    let timeout = 15

    let urlAsString = "http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team12/main_requests.php"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!

    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url,
        cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
        timeoutInterval: 15.0)

    urlRequest.HTTPMethod = httpMethod

    let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    println("success2")

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest,
        queue: queue,
        completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,
            data: NSData!,
            error: NSError!) in

            if data.length > 0 && error == nil{
                let html = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            } else if data.length == 0 && error == nil{
                println("Nothing was downloaded")
            } else if error != nil{
                println("Error happened = \(error)")
            }

            if data.length > 0 && error == nil {
                let html = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                var newArrayofDicts : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                var arrayOfDicts : NSMutableArray? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:nil) as? NSMutableArray
                println("successmutable")

                if arrayOfDicts != nil {
                    for item in arrayOfDicts! {

                        if var dict  = item as? NSMutableDictionary{

                            if  dict["subject"] != nil{
                                self.postSubject = dict["subject"] as String
                                self.postDescription = dict["subject"] as String
                                self.postDate = dict["date"] as String
                            self.postArray.append([self.postSubject,self.postDescription,self.postDate])
                                println("successpost")

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
    sleep(1)
}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    fetchData()
    tableView.reloadData()
    println("successanime")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return postArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    println("successoverride")

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UpdateCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        as UITableViewCell
    println("successupdatecell")

    cell.textLabel.text = postArray[indexPath.row][1]

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = postArray[indexPath.row][2]

    println("success3")
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Performing a segue from a table view cell has nothing to do with Swift, since it takes no code to do it. If you're talking about passing data to the next controller, do some searching. There are hundreds of answers on SO about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
...
}
```

Or you can do it straight in the storyboard by ctrl dragging the prototype cell to the next `viewController`.

Hope this helps!!

**Edit**

If you want to segue to the next `view controller` programmatically, then you can do either:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueName", sender: nil)
```

Or:

```
presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: It creates a segue when we do what you stated but then it wont transition to the new view controller when we run it in the simulator.